# Allow to change metadata of documents within document set

Tags: 2016, document-set

I have a requirement that allows documents within a Document Set to inherit the metadata from the document set when adding new ones. Not problem at all because I activate the Share option in the Document Set settings. The problem comes when I try to modify a value of one of the shared columns for a single document. I am not able to set the value that I want when the column is shared. So the requirement cannot be achieved.
I only can think of an event receiver for ItemAdding to copy original values from the Document Set and having all the shared columns disabled.
Any idea in how to achieve this OOB?